# Deploying my Next.js app with Ionos server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, apache, next.js, ionos

I'm using Next.js for the first time, after using CRA for a long time. I exported the project with `npm run build` but it sounds more complicated to send to my server.

My Apache server and domains are managed on Ionos (ex One&One). I have no skills in Node.js, and I thought I had to send the build folder to my server as I did with CRA apps. I also tried to see if I could send my Next.js app to my server with the help of Vercel, but I didn't see anything about it.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65643588/how-to-deploy-next-js-app-without-node-js-server), but there's no answer yet.

Comment: Is there a specific problem you are getting when you try to deploy your app? Perhaps, do you get an error? Might it be worth a try to use the way you used to use with CRA apps?

Comment: `"build": "next build && next export"` - will export to the default `out` folder, the static pages get exported to .html files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deployed my website with Vercel, with a custom domain from Ionos. That was that easy! Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

IONOS offers a similar approach to Vercel and Netlify named [Deploy Now](https://www.ionos.com/hosting/deploy-now) that offers static hosting for [NextJS](https://docs.ionos.space/docs/from-cmd-line/#nextjs-site) as well.
Maybe that meets your requirements already. But it doesn't offer a NodeJS runtime for using NextJS in a SSR or hybrid variant.