# Azure Next.js deployment. Required structure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, next.js

I already have next.js application running as Azure Web Service with the structure below:

[image: current working example]

But I cannot find any information which folders is required exactly. Deploying to Vercel is out of scope because main requirement is to use Azure Web Applications. My project using server-side rendering so the folder ".next" has been created with `next build` command and looks like this

[image: next build]

`next export` is out of scope too because of SSR.

**Questions are:**

1. In addition to the .next folder which folders and files do I need also?
2. Should I have "server.js" in the site root because redirect rule and iisnode behavior are set in the `web.config`?
3. Can I deploy only .next folder? If yes how server will start in Azure Web App service?

Thank you!

Comment: But what about iisnode? Site uses SSR so it needs node server

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, the `web.config` is required on Windows environment. Simply put, the `web.config` file is an XML file that IIS used for your site configuration.

About the file structure, you could use `next export` to generate an `out` folder.

[image]

And deploy only `out` folder to KuDu, and add the start command in the Configurations on Portal:

```
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa
```

[image]

Please have a look at these articles:

1. [Configuring & Optimizing your Node.js app in an Azure App Service](https://www.dvginteractive.com/configuring-optimizing-your-node-js-app-in-an-azure-app-service/)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61835649/13586071

Comment: As I already said `export` cannot be used because site is using server side rendering. But thank you for the command. Will try.